# Volume up/down function keys limited to gnome-volume-control "Unamplified 100%" level

Tags: gnome, audio

Using GUI `gnome-volume-control`:

```
                             Sound Preferences
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Output Volume: [--------------+      ]
                             ||
                  Unamplified 100%
```

the volume can be adjusted at will. When using the keyboard volume-up and volume-down function keys the volume may be lowered at will but raising the volume is limited to the "Unamplified 100%" level.

Is there a way around this limitation?

> Linux road 2.6.32-28-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 10 21:21:01 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems does not occur in `Ubuntu 11.10 Linux road 3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP`

Comment: are you saying upgrading is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I don't think there is any way around this.

It seems like the integration between the pulseaudio and gnome-media volume settings is still problematic. See for example:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1358021
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/325215
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677681

Seems like the only way to fix this is for someone to [write a patch](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677681) for gnome-media's gnome-volume-control.